# std::vector doesn't call destructor on reassignment

Tags: c++, memory, vector, destructor

I'm trying to use a `std::vector` to hold some `S` instances. However, when I reassign a member of the vector, the destructor isn't called on the previous tenant:

### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct S {
    int index_;
    S(int index) : index_(index) {
        std::cout << "Calling S " << index_ << " constructor\n";
    }
    S(const S& other) : index_(other.index_) {
        std::cout << "Calling S " << index_ << " copy constructor\n";
    }
    ~S() {
        std::cout << "Calling S " << index_ << " destructor\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<S> v;
    v.reserve(10); // Let's not worry about copy constructors
    std::cout << "# Created vector\n";
    v.emplace_back(0);
    v.emplace_back(1);
    v.emplace_back(2);
    std::cout << "# Replacing\n";
    v[1] = S(3); // This doesn't destruct S(1) that was here

    // I can manually call the destructor before I reassign but is that
    // something I should do()?
    // v[1].~S();

    std::cout << "# End scope\n";
}
```

### Output

```
# Created vector
Calling S 0 constructor
Calling S 1 constructor
Calling S 2 constructor
# Replacing
Calling S 3 constructor
Calling S 3 destructor
# End scope
Calling S 2 destructor
Calling S 3 destructor
Calling S 0 destructor
```

### Question

So it looks like `S(1)` at position `1` is never destructed. As I noted in the code, I can manually call the destructor before I reassign it, but I'm not sure if that's a good idea. Is it, and if not, what do you suggest? Also, is there

### Connections to what I really want

In the real code, I'm playing with binary trees and I thought it would be fun to make the nodes be members of a vector and point to each other with indices into the vector (getting me contiguous memory cache benefits, 32bit indices instead of 64bit pointers, and something different to play with). But eventually, I need to do some operations with the tree which means moving/deleting elements, so I want the destructor to be called for an element removed (and I'll use a `std::set` or something to keep track of holes in the vector).

Comment: You forgot to instrument `operator=`.

Comment: A destructor is not called on assignment (or "reassignment" if you prefer)..

Comment: @Miles Budnek and move construction/move assignment as well (for completeness)..

Comment: @JesperJuhl True, but no default move constructor/assignment operator will be generated if there's a user-provided copy one, so missing those will be less mysterious.

Comment: @Miles Budnek I'm aware of that. My point was just for completeness, if OP later also wanted to test what happens in certain cases when the type is movable (like if resizing a vector of objects that are move_if_noexcept == true). You know, just to get a more complete picture.

Comment: See [CopyAssignable concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assigning to the vector element will invoke the copy assignment operator, not the copy constructor. Here's what you need

```
struct S {
    int index_;
    S(int index) : index_(index) {
        std::cout << "Calling S " << index_ << " constructor\n";
    }
    S(const S& other) : index_(other.index_) {
        std::cout << "Calling S " << index_ << " copy constructor\n";
    }

    // added
    S& operator=(const S& other) {
        if (this == &other) { return *this; }
        std::cout << "Calling S " << index_ << " copy assignment\n";
        index_ = other.index_;
        return *this;
    }

    ~S() {
        std::cout << "Calling S " << index_ << " destructor\n";
    }
};
```

Assigning doesn't destroy the existing object, it *assigns* to it. You can reproduce this with a simpler case

```
int main() {
    S s1(1);
    s1 = S(2); // assignment, not destruction/construction. same idea
}
```

If your object owns some resource you'll find that the assignment operator does similar things to both the destructor and the copy constructor. You can [read about the rule of 3 here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) which expands to the *rule of 5* with the addition of move operations.

Comment: The downvoters should definitely state why they downvoted.

Comment: You mention the rule of 3 and 5, maybe add the rule of 0 for completeness.

Comment: @JesperJuhl. It's not really relevant to the answer but sure

Comment: Thanks. That last example really did it.